# Is it possible to check a FLV for data corruption?

Tags: flv, checksum

I have some FLV videos and I'd like to check them for possibile data corruption, even if I'm able to play them without problems. I don't really know if FLV videos store an embedded checksum string for this kind of purposes. My operating system of choice is GNU/Linux. Thanks.

Comment: Apart from the file extension, this is an exact dupe of method and means with your earlier question that a merge sounds better: http://superuser.com/questions/129752/is-it-possible-to-check-a-pdf-for-data-corruption

Answer (score 0):

[See my question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894903/how-can-i-validate-a-video-file-from-a-script) for some ideas.